# How can I select users based on their reputations in a specific period?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

Here is my table structure:

```
-- users
+----+--------+--------------------+
| id |  name  | other columns ... 
+----+--------+--------------------+

-- votes
+----+---------+---------+-------+------------+
| id | user_id | post_id | value | date_time  |
+----+---------+---------+-------+------------+
| 1  | 234234  | 3443    | 1     | 1442684886 | -- For example
+----+---------+---------+-------+------------+
```

I want to select top 20 users in last week. How can I do that?

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT SUM(v.value) score , u.*
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN votes
ON u.id = v.user_id
WHERE v.date_time >  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 week)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

But my query returns just one row.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(value) 
FROM users  JOIN votes 
ON u.id = v.user_id 
WHERE v.date_time >  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 week) 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY sum(value) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Why didn't you select `users` columns?

Comment: It is just working example you can add after sum(value), column1,column2. Or before sum(value) just make SELECT *, sum(value) FROM ...